# Delegate call with a synchronously presented view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My ViewController is a delegate. It is getting a delegate call with BOOL return value. For that to answer, I need to present another custom viewController containing yes or no, and return the answer in the delegate call. 
The problem is presentviewControllerAnimated:completion: is asynchronous.

Any advice?

Comment: you may think of making the delegate call async as well, by using blocks. Is that your custom delegate protocol?

Comment: Yes. A custom protocol. A block passed is a good idea. I will try that and report back.